# How to call setState outside class/stateful widget?

Tags: dart, flutter, state

I have the following variables

```
String _warningMessage;
bool _warningVisibility;
```

Which I want to update via a Class which implements an interface

```
class _UserSignupInterface extends _SignupSelectUsernamePageState
    implements UserSignupInterface {
  @override
  void onSuccess() {
    _hideWarning();
    _navigateToUserPage();
  }

  @override
  void onError(String message) {
    _isSignupClickable = true;

    if(message != null) {
      _displayWarning(message);
    }
  }
}
```

with the _displayWarning code (which is inside the `_SignupSelectUsernamePageState`)

```
void _displayWarning(String message) {
    if (message != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget._warningMessage = message;
        widget._warningVisibility = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

However, whenever I call the `_displayWarning(message)` from outside the `_SignupSelectUsernamePageState`. I get an error saying

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor
```

Is there a proper way of updating these variable states outside their class? Which in my case, I'm calling the `_displayWarning(message)` from another class that implements an interface

Comment: Well, these values are mainly changed only by the class _UserSignupInterface so I guess it's safe to say that these are changed externally. My main problem is changing their state since I really have to change them within the implemented methods of the interface

Comment: sorry, I hit the send button in the comment before the answer was ready! 

Comment: For those who are reading this, and are having the same question. Learn how to use the provider package, or bloc package or other state management packages. It will be very helpful especially in the long run, and you will almost never need to use setState again. It might be difficult to understand for beginners, but trust me. It's very worth learning if you're planning to use flutter for a long time or in medium to large scale projects.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide whether this is a value that is changed internally within the widget, or if that's a value that changes externally to it.

If it's internal, the common thing is to place them in the `State` class with the _ on them, they could start with a value for instance set on `initState` and every time they change you call `setState` to indicate that.

However, if they change outside the widget, then you place them on the `StatefulWidget` class (as you seem to have done), you leave them without the _ as they are actually public and you even make them final and place them in the constructor to allow them to be set.

In this last case, if in the `State` class you must be aware of a change in the widget, you can implement `didUpdateWidget`, but that's not mandatory.

Of course you can mix both things, having a `_warningMessage` in the `State`, so you can update it with `setState`, but with an initial value defined in `initState` that comes from the widget.

Again, if the widget changes externally, you can again update the value of the `_warningMessage` with the new widgets value.

Something like that: (I didn't test this code)

```dart
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  YourWidget({this.warningMessage});

  final String warningMessage;

  @override
  State<YourWidget> createState() => new _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  String _warningMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _warningMessage = widget.warningMessage;
  }

  @override
  didUpdateWidget(ReorderableListSimple oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _warningMessage = widget.warningMessage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(_warningMessage),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Change Message"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _warningMessage = "new message from within the State class";
            });
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So in this example you can change the `warningMessage` externally, like in the `parent` Widget you are able to pass a different message. However, if you need, you can also set it internally using `setState`, as it's happening in the button's `onPressed`.

What you might check is wether you actually need that property exposed in the `Widget`, maybe you don't! Then, the example would look like that:

```dart
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<YourWidget> createState() => new _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  String _warningMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _warningMessage = "default message, no need for widget";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(_warningMessage),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Change Message"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _warningMessage = "new message from within the State class";
            });
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm still a little confused. Because if I use set state, I get the error that I stated on my question. Am I supposed to call the constructor instead of the setState?

Comment: This would work as I've tried this before. But, since I am using a class that implements an interface to hopefully control the state, it gives me an error. Both the interface and the error are stated at the question. But thank you for helping. Im still figuring out ways to actually change the states from the interface

Comment: Then place your variable in the UserSignupInterface, what is wrong is placing it in the StatefulWidget.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a static value in the state of your widget class, then when you build the widget, set it's value to the widget. So whenever you want to call it to `setState()`, just call the static value.